# How to delete password for current account

Tags: sudo, password, accounts

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my new desktop. However, I want to erase the password of it. I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281074/can-i-set-my-user-account-to-have-no-password). I now can successfully login with out password, but I cannot use `sudo` command. It prompt me to enter my password. I tried both empty and the old one. Neither of them will work. How to solve that problem?

Comment: what you get when you enter any command preceding with `sudo` ?

Comment: [sudo] password for [myusername]:

Comment: I mean after you enter `[sudo] password for [myusername]`, what error message you get ?

Comment: Sorry try again

Comment: That is actually a very good protection.  You do realize that removing that protection would remove any kind of protection from your system, right?

Comment: Yeah... However I wanna deploy a `Hadoop` cluster and password-less login is required. T-T

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: IMHO, this is a very bad idea. You should not erase the password of an account.

As explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281074/can-i-set-my-user-account-to-have-no-password), you have to disable the password check in `sudo`, editing the `sudo` configuration file.

Note that the order is important. You have to change sudo configuration **before** to erase the password. If it is to late, you can simply set a new password, change the configuration and delete the password again.

Comment: Yeah, like you said, I first did `sudo visudo` and add `[myusername] ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`  in the file; next, I ran `sudo passwd [myusername] -d` to delete the password. After that I can actually login my account without password. However, in that circumstances, I cannot use `sudo` command, like I put it in the question.